# groupby and get_group does not give the same result

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to get the count of unique values in a column using groupby. However I get different results if I just look at groupby results (which are printed for every group) and if I use get_group(). But the results I get is not same for the first method. What is the problem here?

```
print "Groupby:",bigDF[bigDF.Class == "apple"].groupby('sizeBin').customerId.nunique()
print "Selection:",bigDF[(bigDF.Class == "apple")&(bigDF.sizeBin == 0)].customerId.nunique()
print "Get group:",bigDF[bigDF.Class == "apple"].groupby('sizeBin').get_group(0).customerId.nunique()
Groupby: sizeBin
0       6
1      14
5      26
10     34
20     32
50      3
100     3
200     7
500     0
Name: customerId, dtype: int64
Selection: 34
Get group: 34
```

I should also note the data types, pd.info() gives me the following, so the sizeBin is a category:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 224903 entries, 0 to 20616
Data columns (total 3 columns):
customerId  224903 non-null int64
Class       224903 non-null object
sizeBin     224903 non-null category
dtypes: category(1), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 5.4+ MB
```

Comment: hmm, this looks strange indeed. Could you upload the df you used?

Comment: using your code on my test dataset, all works